# using getter-setter

Tags: c#, setter, getter

[image]

So this is what the final product needs to look like.

I have to use a getter and setter which I don't really understand how to use.

Once the User hits Calc Payroll it will show up in the listbox to the right, and then when the user clicks show list, the label down below will update with just the name and the gross pay.

private void calcButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double rate = 0;
            double hours = 0;
            double withhold = 0;

```
        if (this.nameTextBox.Text != "")
        {
            infoListBox.Items.Add("Name: " + this.nameTextBox.Text);
        }


        if (this.hoursTextBox.Text != "")
        {
            infoListBox.Items.Add("Hours: " + this.hoursTextBox.Text);
        }

        if(this.rateTextBox.Text != "")
        {
            infoListBox.Items.Add("Rate: " + this.rateTextBox.Text);
        }

        if (this.withHoldingTextBox.Text != "") ;
        {
            infoListBox.Items.Add("Withholding Amount: " + this.withHoldingTextBox.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

}

So basically I just printed all the information from the user to the list box

here is the new class so far

```
  class Employees
{
    //Fields
    private double _hours;
    private double _rate;
    private double _withhold;
    private string _name;
    // Constructor
    public Employees(double rate, double hours, double withhold, string name)
    {
        _hours = hours;
        _rate = rate;
        _withhold = withhold;
        _name = name;

    }

    //Rate Property
    public double rate
    {
        get { return _rate; }
        set { _rate = value; }
    }

    public double hours
    {
        get { return _hours; }
        set { _hours = value; }

    }

    public double withhold
    {
        get { return _withhold; }
        set { _withhold = value; }

    }
    //get gross pay
    public double grosspay
    {
        get { return _hours * _rate + _withhold; }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Your link is broken ..

Comment: http://i986.photobucket.com/albums/ae350/muderducker/F72589EF-75AE-498C-8929-68E76B35BF5A.jpg

Comment: I fixed the image in your OP, please approve my edit

Comment: I don't understand the link between _"using getter-setter, and more"_ and your gui/buttons/listbox. A getter/setter are used for properties. Check this: _Using Properties (C# Programming Guide)_ https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04.aspx

Comment: Have you read (and understood) [properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) and the [properties tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa288470.aspx)? Or are you talking about a different kind of "getter" and "setter"? If so, please elaborate on what you mean.

Comment: What don't you understand about `getters`/`setters` and where do you need to use them? Some code would be helpful.

Comment: So I understand You make a new class for them so in this case I would have to make a getter and setter for the name, hours, gross pay, payrate and such, I guess I don't understand what exactly they do and how to use them appropriately.

Comment: [Taking a screen capture (printing your screen)](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/take-screen-capture-print-screen#take-screen-capture-print-screen=windows-7)

Comment: It looks like your trying to find a way to use a solution without knowing the actual problem. What is the exact problem you are having?

Comment: It seems like this assignment is too advanced for your level of knowledge. As this is probably some kind of programming course, you (re-)read the previous material and only continue when you feel like you have a firm understanding of the basic concepts leading up to this.

Comment: I will be posting code soon, you're right this is a programming course and he briefly went over the material without example on how to use code.

Comment: Unrelated recommendation: use `String.IsNullOrEmpty(nameTextBox.Text)` instead of `nameTextBox.Text != ""`

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind your Properties (getter and setter) to the content of your controls.

Like this:

```
private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
```

And in your xaml code you use:

```
<Label Name="Name" Content="{Binding Name}" />
```

you have to bind the name of your property in the content as shown above.

If you need more information about Databinding look here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140621/WPF-Tutorial-Concept-Binding

In this context, you may have a look at the MVVM-Pattern:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/100175/Model-View-ViewModel-MVVM-Explained

Let me know if this helps you!